# Create a dictionary in swift with alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Im trying to create a web request using alamofire in swift , by request object should be like this

```
{
  "warranty": 0,
  "descriptions": "string",
  "product_name": "string",
  "purchase_date": "23/10/2016",
  "product_image": "string",
  "product_receipt": "string",
  "serial_number": "string",
  "barcode_image": "string",
  "serial_number_image": "string",
  "product": {
    "id": 1
  },
  "user": {
    "id": 12
  }
}
```

So in order to get this i have put my code as this

```
let parameters :[String:AnyObject] = [
            "warranty":product.warrenty,
            "descriptions":product.longDescription,
            "product_name":product.initialName,
            "purchase_date":product.purchaseDate,
            "serial_number":product.serialCode,
            "product": [
                "id":product.id
            ],
            "user": [
                "id":userDefaults.getCustomerId()
            ]
        ]
```

But i when i do the request it seems that server doesn't accept this format , probably the way i assign

```
"product": {
        "id": 1
      },
      "user": {
        "id": 12
      }
```

is not correct , what is the issue in here ? can some one point me the issue that i do here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and the problem was, i was missing the encoding option which you need to set .JSON. Match the below line with yours.

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, strURL, parameters: parameter as? [String : AnyObject], encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { (response: Response<AnyObject, NSError>) in
```